# Are we allowed to choose infinite number of elements from an infinite set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> $f$ is surjective $\implies f$ has right inverse.

Suppose $f$ is surjective. Then for any $b \in B$ there's at least one $a \in A$ such that $f(a) = b$. Choose one such $a$ for each $b$ and define $g: B \implies A$ by letting $g(b)$ the chosen $a$. Then $f(g(b)) = b$, so $f \circ g= 1_B$.

Since surjective functions allow any number of arrows each from different points in the domain onto a single point in the codomain, the proof of the given statement depends on making possibly infinite number of choices (one $a \in A$ with $f(a) = b$ for each $b \in B$).

Apparently selecting an infinite number of elements is a big deal and a problem. Why is that? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a big deal or a problem, but it does require the Axiom of Choice.

Here's the point. We want to base our math on set theory. In elementary situations sets are just things that have elements, and the way they work is just the way things with elements obviously work. That's the level at which you'd say what's the big deal, we just select one of these and one of those and we have our inverse  function.

*But* the actual truth is we want to be able to *prove* things about sets, without any fuzziness about how they work. For that we need axioms; the only things we're allowed to say about sets are things that follow from the axioms. (At least in theory it should be possible for a computer to verify the correctness of a proof, without "understanding" anything. So simply relying on our intuitive ideas about how sets should work is not going to fly - we need axioms, so then we can verify carefully that everything follows from the axioms. So we know exactly what we're assuming.)

Now your inverse function is, like more or less everything else, a *set* (a function is a set of ordered pairs such that blah blah). And without the Axiom of Choice, the other axioms of set theory simply do not allow you to prove that that set exists.

[Insert here comments already covered in Peter Smith's answer.]

Comment: Suppose we don't know Axiom of Choice and simply make infinite number of choices wherever we want. What would we be doing wrong? I mean someone must have thought there was a problem with this sort of choosing before he came up with Axiom of Choice.

Comment: Sounds like you missed my point. What you'd be doing wrong is there's simply nothing in the axioms that allows you to make infinitely many choices. There's nothing wrong with making infinitely many choices in a naive/intuitive setting. But that's a different game - _if_ we're trying to make sure that everything we do is allowed by the axioms then we simply cannot make infinitely many choices, unless we assume the Axiom of Choice. It's not that the other axioms _say_ you can't do that. But they don't say you _can_ do that, and you're not allowed to do anything except what the axioms allow.

Comment: Yes, people _did_ make infinitely many choices long before anyone mentioned AC. But that was before they started trying to _axiomatize_ set theory.

Comment: Ok, I see. I find it very counter-intuitive that a handful of axioms cover every possible situation in math. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, but a handful of axioms doesn't cover everything! There are plenty of questions that the axioms of set theory do not settle. And there are theorems due to Godel saying, _very_ roughly and imprecisely, that that's the way it is - we will never find that handful of axioms that cover everything. The standard axioms of set theory _do_ allow to do most things that most mathematicians other than set theorists or logicians want to do.

Comment: I think it might help to discuss *why* we are not allowed to "just make infinitely many choices": a proof has a finite number of steps.

Comment: Of course we can't literally make infinitely many choices, that's obviously nonsense. It's so obviously nonsense that when you see a person use the phrase it should be clear it's not meant literally. In the sense in which the OP and I have been using the phrase, he _did_ "make  infinitely many choices" in his proof. With only finitely many keystrokes.

Answer (score 5):

The claim that any surjective function has a right inverse is indeed (against standard background assumptions) equivalent to Axiom of Choice. There are whole books on the Axiom of Choice, and on the costs and benefits of accepting it (it has surprising consequences).

[The Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_choice) is not a bad place to start finding out more about AC.

And for a more discursive, very informative, article you could read [this online encyclopaedia entry](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/axiom-choice/).